# Automatically remove linebreaks from HTML file

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm currently working on my own grid-sized framework. It's working as I want so far. However, there's this space between the columns. (Please see this [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/2hjgso1a/1/))

I've already found that the reason this space is there is because of the linebreaks in HTML.

```
<div class="UIcolumn">
    1
</div>
<div class="UIcolumn">
    2
</div>
```

You don't see this space in the second row, where I removed the linebreak between the two columns, and there isn't any space in between.

```
<div class="UIcolumn">
    6
</div><div class="UIcolumn">
    7
</div>
```

I'm looking for a way to automatically remove all these linebreaks. It's not an option to do this by hand as the pages will grow larger and larger.

I've tried removing linebreaks by using `$('body').html($('body').html().replace('\n',''))`, which definitely didn't work. I've searched around on [Google](https://www.bing.com/), but couldn't find anything that fixes my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By the time you care about the line breaks, they're not line breaks in source code anymore. They're whitespace text nodes in the DOM. You can use a [`NodeIterator`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeIterator) to find and remove them:

```
function removeWhitespace(rootNode) {
  var nodeIterator = document.createNodeIterator(
    // Node to use as root
    rootNode,

    // Only consider nodes that are text nodes
    NodeFilter.SHOW_TEXT,

    // Object containing the function to use for the acceptNode method
    // of the NodeFilter
    { acceptNode: function(node) {
        // Accept nodes containing only whitespace
        if ( /^\s*$/.test(node.data) ) {
          return NodeFilter.FILTER_ACCEPT;
        } else {
          return NodeFilter.FILTER_SKIP;
        }
      }
    }
  );

  // Remove every empty text node that is a child of root
  var node;

  while ((node = nodeIterator.nextNode())) {
    node.parentNode.removeChild(node);
  }
}
```

This `removeWhitespace` function takes a [`Node`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node), not a jQuery object, and is based heavily on the example on MDN's reference for [`NodeFilter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeFilter).

Comment: I had overlooked this answer. This works amazing. This way, text that's placed in a row (and not inside a column) is also shown.

Answer (score 1):

This is white spaces, so can remove it using `font-size:0` on containers and add `font-size:initial` to child elements like this :

**UPDATE**

After testing by @InzeNL this will work by also adding a JS line `row.css('fontSize',0)`

```js
$(function() {
  UIresponsive();
  $(window).resize(UIresponsive);

  function UIresponsive() {
    var GRIDWIDTH = 12;

    var currentSize = 'Small';

    var rows = $('[class^=UIrow],[class*=" UIrow"]');
    var columns = $('[class^=UIcolumn],[class*=" UIcolumn"]');

    rows.each(function() {
      var row = $(this);

      setSize(row, 'row');

      row.width(row.parent().width() - getWidthDifference(row));
    });

    columns.each(function() {
      var column = $(this);
      var row = column.parent();

      column.css('display', 'inline-block');

      setSize(column, 'column');

      var columnSize = Number(column.data('UIcolumn' + currentSize + 'Size'));
      var rowSize = Number(row.data('UIrow' + currentSize + 'Size'));

      if (isNaN(rowSize)) {
        rowSize = GRIDWIDTH;
      }
      if (columnSize > rowSize) {
        columnSize = rowSize;
      }

      column.width(Math.floor(columnSize / rowSize * row.width() - getWidthDifference(column)));
    });

    function setSize(element, type) {
      var elementClass = element.attr('class');

      if (elementClass.indexOf('UI' + type + '-') == 0 || elementClass.indexOf(' UI' + type + '-') >= 0) {
        elementClass.split(' ').forEach(function(value, i) {
          if (value.indexOf('UI' + type + '-') == 0) {
            var sizes = value.replace('UI' + type + '-', '').split('-');
            if (sizes[0] != undefined) {
              element.data('UI' + type + 'SmallSize', sizes[0]);
            } else {
              element.data('UI' + type + 'SmallSize', GRIDWIDTH);
            }
            if (sizes[1] != undefined) {
              element.data('UI' + type + 'MediumSize', sizes[0]);
            } else {
              element.data('UI' + type + 'MediumSize', element.data('UI' + type + 'SmallSize'));
            }
            if (sizes[2] != undefined) {
              element.data('UI' + type + 'BigSize', sizes[0]);
            } else {
              element.data('UI' + type + 'BigSize', element.data('UI' + type + 'MediumSize'));
            }
            if (sizes[3] != undefined) {
              element.data('UI' + type + 'HugeSize', sizes[0]);
            } else {
              element.data('UI' + type + 'HugeSize', element.data('UI' + type + 'BigSizeSize'));
            }

            element.removeClass(value);
            element.addClass('UI' + type);
          }
        });
      } else if (element.data('UI' + type + currentSize + 'Size') == undefined) {
        if (type == 'column') {
          element.data('UIcolumnSmallSize', 1);
          element.data('UIcolumnMediumSize', 1);
          element.data('UIcolumnBigSize', 1);
          element.data('UIcolumnHugeSize', 1);
        } else {
          element.data('UIrowSmallSize', GRIDWIDTH);
          element.data('UIrowMediumSize', GRIDWIDTH);
          element.data('UIrowBigSize', GRIDWIDTH);
          element.data('UIrowHugeSize', GRIDWIDTH);
        }
      }
    }

    function getWidthDifference(element) {
      return Number(element.css('borderLeftWidth').replace('px', '')) +
        Number(element.css('borderRightWidth').replace('px', '')) +
        Number(element.css('marginLeft').replace('px', '')) +
        Number(element.css('marginRight').replace('px', '')) +
        Number(element.css('paddingLeft').replace('px', '')) +
        Number(element.css('paddingRight').replace('px', ''));
    }
  }
});
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: none;
  outline-offset: 0;
  outline: none;
}

.UIrow {
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 0;
}


.UIcolumn {
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid black;
  vertical-align: top;
  font-size: initial;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="UIrow-4">
  <div class="UIcolumn">
    1
  </div>
  <div class="UIcolumn">
    2
  </div>
  <div class="UIcolumn">
    3
  </div>
  <div class="UIcolumn">
    4
  </div>
  <div class="UIcolumn">
    5
  </div>
</div>
<div class="UIrow-2 UIcolumn-6">
  <div class="UIcolumn">
    6
  </div>
  <div class="UIcolumn">
    7
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This would indeed work for the first row. However, this framework has the option to have a row be a column as well (see second row), and it that case it doesn't work [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/2hjgso1a/2/)

Comment: @InzeNL ok i see, so it's very dependant on the framework you are using

Comment: Managed to solve this by adding a line to the JavaScript [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/2hjgso1a/3/) `row.css('fontSize',0);` which would override the column fontSize

Comment: @InzeNL yes like this you will use inline styles ;)

Comment: @InzeNL i will then add this to my answer if you don't mind